# calculating the rmse when my data does not align correctly

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have this data where I am trying to calculate the rmse of the actual and predicted values:

Head

```
# A time tibble: 6 x 4
# Index: index
  IRI_KEY index      value key   
    <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <fct> 
1  648459 2005-01-31  1.43 actual
2  648459 2005-02-07  1.16 actual
3  648459 2005-02-14  1.22 actual
4  648459 2005-02-21  1.16 actual
5  648459 2005-02-28  1.04 actual
6  648459 2005-03-07  1.45 actual
```

Tail

```
# A time tibble: 6 x 4
# Index: index
  IRI_KEY index      value key    
    <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <fct>  
1      NA 2011-12-12  1.79 predict
2      NA 2011-12-19  1.76 predict
3      NA 2011-12-26  1.76 predict
4      NA 2012-01-02  1.67 predict
5      NA 2012-01-09  1.64 predict
6      NA 2012-01-16  1.69 predict
```

Firstly I am trying to fill the NA values in with the same ID key in that column (these ID keys change on each data frame). So the "actual" results have an ID Key assigned to them but the "Predict" result do not for some reason.

Secondly I am trying to calculate the rmse of the "actual" and "predicted". What I have returns "NaN" due to the NA values in the two columns "actual" and "predict" after I use the `spread` function.

How can I calculate the rmse or how can I configure the data so that the dates match?

I trained a model until the date `2011-01-24` and tested it from `2011-01-24` to `2012-01-16`

```
 rmse_calculation <- 
    df %>%
      spread(key = key, value = value) %>%
    rename(truth    = actual,
           estimate = predict)
  rmse(truth, estimate)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(IRI_KEY = c(648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 
648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, 648459, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), index = structure(c(12814, 12821, 12828, 12835, 12842, 
12849, 12856, 12863, 12870, 12877, 12884, 12891, 12898, 12905, 
12912, 12919, 12926, 12933, 12940, 12947, 12954, 12961, 12968, 
12975, 12982, 12989, 12996, 13003, 13010, 13017, 13024, 13031, 
13038, 13045, 13052, 13059, 13066, 13073, 13080, 13087, 13094, 
13101, 13108, 13115, 13122, 13129, 13136, 13143, 13150, 13157, 
13164, 13171, 13178, 13185, 13192, 13199, 13206, 13213, 13220, 
13227, 13234, 13241, 13248, 13255, 13262, 13269, 13276, 13283, 
13290, 13297, 13304, 13311, 13318, 13325, 13332, 13339, 13346, 
13353, 13360, 13367, 13374, 13381, 13388, 13395, 13402, 13409, 
13416, 13423, 13430, 13437, 13444, 13451, 13458, 13465, 13472, 
13479, 13486, 13493, 13500, 13507, 13514, 13521, 13528, 13535, 
13542, 13549, 13556, 13563, 13570, 13577, 13584, 13591, 13598, 
13605, 13612, 13619, 13626, 13633, 13640, 13647, 13654, 13661, 
13668, 13675, 13682, 13689, 13696, 13703, 13710, 13717, 13724, 
13731, 13738, 13745, 13752, 13759, 13766, 13773, 13780, 13787, 
13794, 13801, 13808, 13815, 13822, 13829, 13836, 13843, 13850, 
13857, 13864, 13871, 13878, 13885, 13892, 13899, 13906, 13913, 
13920, 13927, 13934, 13941, 13948, 13955, 13962, 13969, 13976, 
13983, 13990, 13997, 14004, 14011, 14018, 14025, 14032, 14039, 
14046, 14053, 14060, 14067, 14074, 14081, 14088, 14095, 14102, 
14109, 14116, 14123, 14130, 14137, 14144, 14151, 14158, 14165, 
14172, 14179, 14186, 14193, 14200, 14207, 14214, 14221, 14228, 
14235, 14242, 14249, 14256, 14263, 14270, 14277, 14284, 14291, 
14298, 14305, 14312, 14319, 14326, 14333, 14340, 14347, 14354, 
14361, 14368, 14375, 14382, 14389, 14396, 14403, 14410, 14417, 
14424, 14431, 14438, 14445, 14452, 14459, 14466, 14473, 14480, 
14487, 14494, 14501, 14508, 14515, 14522, 14529, 14536, 14543, 
14550, 14557, 14564, 14571, 14578, 14585, 14592, 14599, 14606, 
14613, 14620, 14627, 14634, 14641, 14648, 14655, 14662, 14669, 
14676, 14683, 14690, 14697, 14704, 14711, 14718, 14725, 14732, 
14739, 14746, 14753, 14760, 14767, 14774, 14781, 14788, 14795, 
14802, 14809, 14816, 14823, 14830, 14837, 14844, 14851, 14858, 
14865, 14872, 14879, 14886, 14893, 14900, 14907, 14914, 14921, 
14928, 14935, 14942, 14949, 14956, 14963, 14970, 14977, 14984, 
14991, 14998, 15005, 15012, 15019, 15026, 15033, 15040, 15047, 
15054, 15061, 15068, 15075, 15082, 15089, 15096, 15103, 15110, 
15117, 15124, 15131, 15138, 15145, 15152, 15159, 15166, 15173, 
15180, 15187, 15194, 15201, 15208, 15215, 15222, 15229, 15236, 
15243, 15250, 15257, 15264, 15271, 15278, 15285, 15292, 15299, 
15306, 15313, 15320, 15327, 15334, 15341, 15348, 15355, 14998, 
15005, 15012, 15019, 15026, 15033, 15040, 15047, 15054, 15061, 
15068, 15075, 15082, 15089, 15096, 15103, 15110, 15117, 15124, 
15131, 15138, 15145, 15152, 15159, 15166, 15173, 15180, 15187, 
15194, 15201, 15208, 15215, 15222, 15229, 15236, 15243, 15250, 
15257, 15264, 15271, 15278, 15285, 15292, 15299, 15306, 15313, 
15320, 15327, 15334, 15341, 15348, 15355), class = "Date"), value = c(1.42824767211314, 
1.15935636773992, 1.21562423396038, 1.16087592721371, 1.03655779775518, 
1.45014602307116, 1.19603891069525, 1.51629361136222, 1.35248187520545, 
1.19313036089064, 1.23466779056019, 1.21321049528827, 1.19503355008839, 
1.25756070009974, 1.4265698115632, 1.62505506289166, 1.41987592239844, 
1.34910786957776, 1.65086551211581, 1.77928559677544, 1.83845338283235, 
1.83580669517815, 1.67750364243548, 1.63087084240032, 1.53321928861015, 
1.51027605545301, 1.63050891497539, 1.4862366729199, 1.76886165853052, 
1.51076508754458, 1.79972192638831, 1.40905379487872, 1.33271255551288, 
1.35204242431244, 1.33470871214462, 1.27922055778867, 1.19085428349673, 
1.16260508468215, 1.20011754027413, 1.08580541093404, 1.23437608684114, 
1.21860360879203, 1.27448459413395, 1.21110406725922, 1.1601869743601, 
1.21755561640455, 1.31757665372039, 1.3375114790927, 1.0713257506421, 
1.34170917203277, 1.21640792427817, 1.23702534970888, 1.30153826689137, 
1.10825732300252, 1.4498640625571, 1.33638090869313, 1.16528603779432, 
1.11272227006406, 1.24456830644998, 1.08932241378247, 1.2616330691761, 
1.24871988673321, 1.2694941591514, 1.25607040153018, 1.42968365090233, 
1.54595667506417, 1.4955572237206, 1.4892478841414, 1.56504325252197, 
1.48020564768688, 1.60796032677947, 1.64874719617122, 1.71994456839498, 
1.52466258015572, 2.00665769675817, 1.5300656898625, 1.56161480192207, 
1.50940919433804, 1.58004290205282, 1.51336116478672, 1.52644487316346, 
1.48834327809579, 1.46930588866215, 1.36631372054513, 1.44059995744445, 
1.5180608970494, 1.41812200439152, 1.49925405818079, 1.31689765959184, 
1.21907772239039, 1.30753278259585, 1.57082329051166, 1.49143144852514, 
1.38216169956339, 1.44188483722575, 1.13440481876605, 1.35646235618919, 
1.47180541887913, 1.40450054293681, 1.27349389048426, 1.29528063459954, 
1.19942539235927, 1.30759474350784, 1.22991541621001, 1.20042686177282, 
1.24226428750839, 1.31647286005394, 1.36705779079172, 1.17554267519, 
1.16899741356497, 1.43296930422939, 1.21387581786617, 1.38582954148396, 
1.28783359001873, 1.21384290720918, 1.3800531898995, 1.42612748362677, 
1.38707139063945, 1.35097838761857, 1.55653136781291, 1.56210596088512, 
1.46432027353204, 1.73308661593706, 1.81117569489508, 1.95852654293544, 
1.93756438714927, 1.66868242849234, 1.73257095484375, 1.61222759440404, 
1.6253033081607, 1.48045275517727, 1.55148523707946, 1.72319831625545, 
1.56521419500555, 1.71621780116811, 1.60341610957045, 1.42595759455634, 
1.38612153699359, 1.31866799689145, 1.24054071692306, 1.51727627953577, 
1.46369642055739, 1.62365073651995, 1.48616110223811, 1.45200956674952, 
1.57953386960066, 1.35567084839722, 1.31102635489236, 1.18306026521603, 
1.34712117984483, 1.48011116841267, 1.31952399321848, 1.28955782668141, 
1.2847877566953, 1.38781149288866, 1.14273437468433, 1.32920929503918, 
1.2625010370967, 1.24823649783691, 1.32533796650272, 1.15633519566998, 
1.35643701026316, 1.26623559190508, 1.2779230360069, 1.39393252918254, 
1.34649076777916, 1.57333920622946, 1.56022699221392, 1.37469189146892, 
1.40291710899725, 1.4280748466788, 1.54743544515232, 1.76335619076727, 
1.64154787821095, 1.59923604539536, 1.87343400218089, 1.64411494469552, 
2.06337974786263, 1.79679434639182, 1.6449219227191, 1.60191406672643, 
1.80552930592686, 1.71079029585556, 1.76324045494208, 1.75172505216794, 
1.75498018535201, 1.50968674188647, 1.71003279170095, 1.54195285019629, 
1.5921076852091, 1.58468618049952, 1.40466129233649, 1.51748231420534, 
1.70208735303382, 1.85091455978708, 1.74926589474411, 1.32473081658656, 
1.48632510896193, 1.49174172910242, 1.27765485727251, 1.42447037214314, 
1.79061536646697, 1.62876010610048, 1.3411075302794, 1.43372361571107, 
1.30745132006153, 1.11947181750234, 1.3814366092412, 1.46127530431355, 
1.29002256883274, 1.2398180314717, 1.39955595479061, 1.23212239602012, 
1.42879839332803, 1.40682720430913, 1.72735766769174, 1.24631738756635, 
1.3074957545204, 1.33889060033108, 1.3199907585375, 1.45011590182187, 
1.47464294283024, 1.63025156324233, 1.43518657525572, 1.70101536967133, 
1.53879821021698, 1.66216734455997, 1.71016735176043, 1.59135918593749, 
1.90867635488099, 1.81890270995124, 1.91974059472128, 1.99327137052795, 
1.93435630760761, 1.70498489998951, 1.94617134446234, 1.79821897461961, 
1.70860912987869, 1.62583692511332, 1.70284656450383, 1.75349832294427, 
1.55992661541648, 1.64923355919767, 1.58374450488874, 1.43099121772556, 
1.6720951989917, 1.63569433069745, 1.56297225511903, 1.37234218101439, 
1.62846496684787, 1.45468005665216, 1.46447402492545, 1.49422003453774, 
1.36416239454076, 1.26665784696327, 1.42621220161668, 1.31906561671418, 
1.56293535063656, 1.41124392931084, 1.48256373828037, 1.5517304198153, 
1.46775941254522, 1.33131685935843, 1.44720659024551, 1.37716132331258, 
1.52882131002331, 1.49772761055849, 1.49598881675741, 1.4436527605176, 
1.49981336417591, 1.48315006689715, 1.51558578205289, 1.42774117545654, 
1.53336088586741, 1.48915800705672, 1.32963057893323, 1.66758248928613, 
1.9868088974245, 1.6013366125517, 1.92183146143593, 2.03298402768403, 
2.04942459105045, 2.05963631611094, 1.94588422660773, 1.96201751711786, 
1.98861196288086, 1.81221909789435, 1.90862937715181, 1.88729319156364, 
1.73284989132999, 1.67492630039261, 1.96341445187649, 1.65044353051518, 
1.56141975468635, 1.53636815843546, 1.51077277695073, 1.69938051312308, 
1.73580450473473, 1.57871171461789, 1.71561146182678, 1.62626622286327, 
1.56926630931672, 1.60160751499099, 1.59430576978708, 1.70308313972817, 
1.60980830874125, 2.10166142081649, 1.70173661542508, 1.70249301702887, 
1.39310069185542, 1.26684098191883, 1.41331947258224, 1.38942452543244, 
1.49664320528791, 1.2603789824492, 1.39558797557555, 1.43708777666337, 
1.59937247371089, 1.52662972813667, 1.55327235669201, 1.36463952847974, 
1.48182556775146, 1.41239170175741, 1.37685943760087, 1.45727766276937, 
1.3575730455734, 1.44108325750848, 1.50900111871182, 1.77063869557307, 
1.97657756150903, 1.8883656161968, 1.95877784079574, 2.24763616539836, 
2.16270152004098, 2.09783115130459, 2.27274727762128, 2.46035830600469, 
2.02426295139333, 2.39422867018116, 1.92394855093771, 2.17810121167828, 
2.00612799115504, 1.78424713919667, 2.0400432816189, 1.79256103489444, 
1.91409478802101, 1.73150194252708, 1.6912418337357, 1.75277447327501, 
1.85091969553689, 1.56679068785437, 1.65536989557469, 1.60663371555237, 
2.01662556616972, 1.67081920134216, 1.66342984073245, 1.89203261364869, 
1.9256563676998, 2.17669290665916, 1.96119726513824, 1.77590077949215, 
1.91168033977827, 1.85350279506872, 1.8255506513295, 1.53524437633556, 
1.5037629155505, 1.45284901948611, 1.49595326670589, 1.4695719361713, 
1.52677696453418, 1.51511572943787, 1.51445931388811, 1.49460322790447, 
1.51590263465507, 1.50960240456058, 1.52183314361577, 1.48856608717673, 
1.52846450808968, 1.51187726330412, 1.45224630607792, 1.57541341759254, 
1.65339389119157, 1.5530652177716, 1.64143401336441, 1.66086748404603, 
1.66333965982899, 1.6648278163954, 1.64606881590278, 1.64903884298644, 
1.65370103757561, 1.63443933109847, 1.62254021970341, 1.56240224916707, 
1.56597342109254, 1.51312911363279, 1.65650202008756, 1.56305567273967, 
1.53024422924801, 1.49368346466127, 1.51304956503642, 1.5722161158099, 
1.59860807361417, 1.50182216056083, 1.60084661780045, 1.55037806375165, 
1.45223419121299, 1.62816386241768, 1.73158686552491, 1.62782065585366, 
1.71864664092992, 1.78757241857122, 1.76051806693622, 1.76237510711282, 
1.67273139326038, 1.63774229399432, 1.69105865330396), key = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("actual", 
"predict"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -416L), index_quo = ~index, index_time_zone = "UTC", class = c("tbl_time", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

The model begins on `2005-01-31` and ends on `2012-01-16` and there are weekly periods. In the model there 364 weeks (364 / 52 = 7 years). I trained the model on the first 6 years (from `2005-01-31` to `2011-01-17)` and test the model on the last year (from week `2011-01-24` to `2012-01-16`).

I have predictions for the last year and I also have the actual values for this period also. I am trying to calculate the rmse for where I have predictions, or the last 52 weeks.

EDIT 2:

So essentially after looking at the `rmse_calculation` table (line 364) I am trying to "push-up" the predict column and then remove all the NA values in the predict column where I will be left with just 52 observations and then I can calculate the rmse for the 52 weeks.

EDIT 3:

Filling in the IRI_KEY column isn´t that important.

Comment: I'd probably encourage you to look into why your predicted values are missing the IRI_KEY value. Your dates don't appear to be unique so it's not going to be easy to merge the data back together. Plus you seem to have 364 "actual" values and only "52" predicted values. Not sure how you would calculate a RMSE with different numbers of observed and predicted values.

Comment: Thanks for the input MrFlick. If you run the following `rmse_calculation %>%
  filter(index == "2011-01-24")` I have two results for the same date a "actual" and a "predict". Whereas if I run `rmse_calculation %>%
  filter(index == "2005-02-28")` I only get 1 result for the "actual". - i.e. no prediction. What I have done is to train the model on 52 weeks * 6 years which gives me 312 results - so the first 312 observations in the data are the training. Then I test the model on the remaining 52 weeks. - I Will edit the original post to explain better.

Comment: @user8959427, it sounds like you think that `index` is a unique key, is that right? If so, perhaps a `left_join` would be more appropriate than a `spread`. Example: `left_join(filter(df, key=="actual"), filter(df, key=="predict") %>% select(index, key, value), by="index")`. (This is obviously hasty code, not sure it gives you the association you need.)

Comment: I added a small edit to the end of the post which hopefully explains a Little more clear what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that we can safely discard `IRI_KEY` in order to expand on the key value, `index`. With this, we can either do a left-join or a spread to get effective the same associations:

```
df %>%
  select(-IRI_KEY) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))
# # A tibble: 52 x 3
#    index      actual predict
#    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 2011-01-24   1.39    1.54
#  2 2011-01-31   1.50    1.50
#  3 2011-02-07   1.26    1.45
#  4 2011-02-14   1.40    1.50
#  5 2011-02-21   1.44    1.47
#  6 2011-02-28   1.60    1.53
#  7 2011-03-07   1.53    1.52
#  8 2011-03-14   1.55    1.51
#  9 2011-03-21   1.36    1.49
# 10 2011-03-28   1.48    1.52
# # ... with 42 more rows
df %>%
  select(-IRI_KEY) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(actual, predict)) %>%
  with(., ModelMetrics::rmse(actual, predict))
# [1] 0.3130566
```

We must use `filter(complete.cases(actual, predict))` because `rmse` expects no `NA` values, and it does not accept the often-standard `na.rm=TRUE` from other R functions.

---

The downside of this `spread` approach is that it discards your `IRI_KEY`, since (as @MrFlick highlighted) it is not being transferred in your prediction step. An alternative approach is to left-join your `predict`ed values onto the same-`index` rows:

```
df %>%
  filter(key == "predict") %>%
  select(index, value) %>%
  left_join(filter(df, key == "actual"), by="index") %>%
  rename(actual = value.y, predict = value.x)
# # A tibble: 52 x 5
#    index      predict IRI_KEY actual key   
#    <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct> 
#  1 2011-01-24    1.54  648459   1.39 actual
#  2 2011-01-31    1.50  648459   1.50 actual
#  3 2011-02-07    1.45  648459   1.26 actual
#  4 2011-02-14    1.50  648459   1.40 actual
#  5 2011-02-21    1.47  648459   1.44 actual
#  6 2011-02-28    1.53  648459   1.60 actual
#  7 2011-03-07    1.52  648459   1.53 actual
#  8 2011-03-14    1.51  648459   1.55 actual
#  9 2011-03-21    1.49  648459   1.36 actual
# 10 2011-03-28    1.52  648459   1.48 actual
# # ... with 42 more rows
```

which allows us the same use of the `rmse` function:

```
df %>%
  filter(key == "predict") %>%
  select(index, value) %>%
  left_join(filter(df, key == "actual"), by="index") %>%
  rename(actual = value.y, predict = value.x) %>%
  with(., ModelMetrics::rmse(actual, predict))
# [1] 0.3130566
```

**N.B.:** I did not start with this approach since the output suggests that I know the prediction values are associated with the `IRI_KEY` values, which I don't know (only you do). If you are not certain that the dates provide sufficient correlation to identify with the keys, then this approach is faulty and can/will result in incorrect deductions later on down your analytical pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think the spread approach is great! One way I was thinking to solve the IRI_KEY column problem. At the step where we take the `df`, we have columns `IRI_KEY`, `index`, `value` and `key` - would it not be possible to populate the NA values IRI_KEY rows with the same IRI_KEY in the other rows? - The IRI_KEY is just a ID column. The NA values were created by an earlier calculation. The "predict" values in this data correspond to the IRI_KEY. A different dataframe has a different IRI_KEY etc.

Comment: The following workds `fill(IRI_KEY) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(actual, predict)) %>%
  with(., ModelMetrics::rmse(actual, predict))
`

Comment: If you need to preserve `IRI_KEY` then use the join approach (or add another step of re-joining `select(df, IRI_KEY, index)`). It sounds like your use of `IRI_KEY` and `index` are a perfect 1-to-1 relationship, is that right?

Comment: The IRI_KEY turns out to not be important within the dataset - I applied what you provided into a function and the function maps the code onto different IRI_KEYs - therefore I preserve the IRI_KEY structure - i.e. each rmse corresponds to an IRI_KEY

Comment: You helped me fix a problem I was having regarding this tutorial - https://www.r-bloggers.com/time-series-deep-learning-forecasting-sunspots-with-keras-stateful-lstm-in-r/